# Numerical characters preventing successful SELECT in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting users' details from a MySQL database and while most usernames are successfully matched, those containing numbers are not.

In my database table I have records, among others, with 'examplename' and 'examplename1' in the user_name column. They are stored as VARCHAR, collation utf8_general_ci.

This returns 'details':

```
SELECT details FROM username_table WHERE user_name = 'examplename'
```

Whereas this does not:

```
SELECT details FROM username_table WHERE user_name = 'examplename1'
```

Why is the numerical character causing  problem in a VARCHAR field? (I've tried as TEXT too, also fails.)

Edit: OK, my mistake. These are simplified examples; I've got JOIN clauses in the actual statements, and by coincidence, of the 28 users in the table, I was making join errors on the only two with numbers in their usernames. Sorry.

Comment: Presumably, nothing in the table matches `'examplename1'`.

Comment: *Strange Behaviour*

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Consider deleting the question as there was no problem to begin with, and the discussion won't help anyone else learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds stupid, but have you tried to extract the query so that your searched term is it's own variable?

something like this:

```
$var_name = "examplename1";
$SQL = "SELECT details FROM username_table WHERE user_name = $var_name";
....
```

This usually works for me when I've got numbers in my query string.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the numerical character causing problem in a VARCHAR field?

MySQL has no trouble searching through VARCHAR fields that contain numerical characters. The most likely explanation is that there is no record in `username_table` with `user_name` set to 'examplename1'

Try this:

```
SELECT details FROM username_table WHERE user_name LIKE 'examplename%'
```

It will show you all records whose `user_name` begins with `examplename`